# TargetParameterCountException in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

What's going on here please?

After the method finish, this error is thrown.

I already tried some other topics, but my case is different.

Any clue?

I am using this Dispatcher, because I had a cross thread problem.

```
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    e.Result = ...;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        (RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler)delegate
        {
            image1.Source = (BitmapImage)e.Result;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` delegate expects parameters, which you do not provide (or use), you could probably do with changing it to an `Action`:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate
{
    image1.Source = (BitmapImage)e.Result;
});
```

If you must use the `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` (which is pointless) you could call the respective `BeginInvoke` overload and provide an empty array of two objects which represents sender and event-args:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler)delegate
{
    image1.Source = (BitmapImage)e.Result;
}, DispatcherPriority.Normal, new object[2]);
```

Comment: I will try that on monday. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, does this compiles? (RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler)delegate. Do I need to change the word delegate to "backgroundWorker.doWork"?

Comment: Both methods compile and throw no expections. You do not need to change anything unless this is not really what you wanted to do in the first place, i just fixed the code you provided, i cannot know if that code does what you want.

Comment: unfortunately, this do not work. This gives me the this error : "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.", which was my older problem.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot a bit of code, you might need to access the application dispatcher if that is the case, i edited it. This is a problem independent of the method call parameters though.

Comment: That is weird, it worked for me either way; Did you not create the Image on the UI thread? If so you need to get the right Dispatcher and invoke on it. You could create a reference to `image1.Dispatcher` outside of the background-worker then you can be sure you have the right one. If this persists please accept my answer as it did solve the initial problem and ask another question so more people get a chance to help out.